# SQL Query Issues

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Having a very hard time wrapping my head around how this should be written,
I have a key made up of a fixed number column and an incrementing number column.

I want to have the select query only return the newest row for each fixed number.

For example:

```
20, 1
20, 2
20, 3 <-- Should only return these rows
25, 1
25, 2 <--
30, 1
30, 2
30, 3 <--
```

Is there to write this in a single query without having to iterate over the results in php?

Comment: Do you only need to display those two columns, or are there other columns in the table that need to be output too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select col1, max(col2) from table group by col1
```

would give you

20 3
25 2
30 3

[SqlFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a202a/1)

Comment: The group by should be on the other column not with the one you are taking the MAX of

Comment: No the OP wanted it the way I have it. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a202a/1

Answer (score 1):

Try this::

```
select max(column1), column2
from table 
group by column2
```

Comment: This is it, you reversed the col names, but it works when switched. I knew it was something simple like this, thanks!